SwiftUI: Hide the tabbar deep in subviews of TabView
Apple's .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar) doesn't work from child views for some reason. So I'm trying to come up with some logic to implement a working approach for tabbar hiding.
EDIT: Pardon, it does work, but it's not being animated. The general solution is to add a state variable and animate it on appear/disappear. But it doesn't work for me. Here is why.
I need to be able to hide the tabbar with animation when navigating to certain subviews of the main tabbar view itself. Let's call them View1 and View2. You can navigate to these views directly, or from View1 to View2. Because of this, I cannot just use onAppear and onDisappear. Moreover, there is a difficulty: if I'm on View1, I start to edge swipe to navigate back, the onAppear of MainView gets called, then I release the gesture, and View1 come back, but its onAppear is not called again. So onAppear and onDisappear - are not an option. It needs to be more state driven - if and only if View1 or View 2 instance exists - the tabbar is hidden.
I'm trying to pass the info about whether tabbar needs to be hidden up the hierarchy using environment.
class TabBarManager: ObservableObject {
    static var shared = TabBarManager()
    @Published var isTabBarVisible: Bool = true
}

struct TabBarVisibilityKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: Bool = true
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var tabBarVisibility: Bool {
        get {
            TabBarManager.shared.isTabBarVisible
            //return self[TabBarVisibilityKey.self]
        }
        set {
            //self[TabBarVisibilityKey.self] = newValue
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                TabBarManager.shared.isTabBarVisible = newValue
            }
        }
    }
}

MainView()
    .toolbar(tabBarManager.isTabBarVisible ? .visible : .hidden, for: .tabBar)

View1/2()
    .environment(\.tabBarVisibility, false)

With this approach it disappears when needed but never appears back.
I know I can pass a @Binding between all of my views, but there are a lot and it feels like an awful approach.
I realize this is a strange usage of everything SwiftUI has to offer, but I'm kind of lost by now - nothing works. So please send help, thanks in advance.

"Apple's .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar) doesn't work from child views for some reason." Can you show a [mcve] of this?

Pardon, it does work, but without animation. The general solution is to add a state variable and animate it on appear/disappear, which is not an option as I mentioned. I used the link you posted before, it works, but the animation looks broken again. Working on that currently

First, I needed to use Preferences instead of Environment to pass smth up the hierarchy, like @Sweeper says here
struct CustomTabBarVisiblePreference: PreferenceKey {
    // nil means "not set"
    static let defaultValue: Bool? = nil

    static func reduce(value: inout Bool?, nextValue: () -> Bool?) {
        guard let next = nextValue() else { return }
        value = next
    }
}

MainView()
    .toolbar(tabbarIsVisible ? .visible : .hidden, for: .tabBar)
    .onPreferenceChange(CustomTabBarVisiblePreference.self) { value in
        if let value {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // manual animation, because tabbar hide/show is not animated by default
                tabbarIsVisible = !value
                withAnimation(DesignSystem.animationEaseInOutFast) {
                    tabbarIsVisible = value
                }
            }
        }
    }

Then use .preference(key: CustomTabBarVisiblePreference.self, value: false) whenever you want it hidden.
One more thing - set .preference(key: CustomTabBarVisiblePreference.self, value: true) somewhere to change it back. As I understood it has to be NOT a parent to the views where you set it to false or setting them to false will stop working. You'll have to play around to see where it works - the important thing is that onPreferenceChange gets called with true value after you close all the false views.
